# Code Coverage Repeated Apex classes

Tags: salesforce, code-coverage, test-class

We are having an issue , where when we run all tests we see some classes repeated. These classes that are repeated are actually incorrectly labeled classes.

Example: Class A and Class B. Run all tests and code coverage shows that Class A has 90% coverage and Class A has 55% coverage.
We believe this is breaking our ide, anyone know how to resolve this?

I have tried clearing the test cache (Setup > Develop > Apex Test Execution > View Test History > Clear Test Data with no change. As well i tried commenting out code that may have called the other class, still no luck.

Interestingly enough this 'bug' is present across our ide's ...dev console, welkins suite, force.com ide... Trying to pin down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

It is present in all the IDE's is because it's also present in your actual Salesforce instance.

Be more specific.

Apex tests run on a server. If you do not have enough coverage you are not allowed to deploy. You probably need to add some tests to the code you'v added to the org. This could also be indication that something else is broken.

Comment: Sorry I’ll try to be more specific. Test class run and compile fine. We have been able to push from sandbox to prod fine. Code coverage is great. Only reason this is an issue , welkins suite ( our 3rd party ide) will not show code coverage with repeated classes, and we suspect these repeated classes are the cause. We only see the classes repeated if we run tests and view a list of all tests in any ide, and some classes are missing . We have checked for dupe ids on classes as well so don’t think that’s it ....